# XQuery returning the whole xml meta data

Tags: xml, xquery

Sorry a complete xquery noob here. I'm trying to write a query to return the dosage, drugname and diagnosis from the following xml document if and only if there is an element "trmt:drugTreatment" present.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clin:Clinic 
xmlns:cids="http://www.example.org/schema/hosptial/clinicIds" 
xmlns:clin="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/clinic" 
xmlns:pat="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/patient" 
xmlns:prov="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/provider" 
xmlns:trmt="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/treatment" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/clinic 
Clinic.xsd ">
  <clin:Patient>
    <pat:patient-id>0001</pat:patient-id>
    <pat:patientName>Thomas Edison</pat:patientName>
    <pat:dob>1991-01-01</pat:dob>
    <pat:treatments>
      <pat:treatment>
        <trmt:providerId>001</trmt:providerId>
        <trmt:diagnosis>Heart</trmt:diagnosis>
        <trmt:drugTreatment>
            <trmt:dosage>12.5mg</trmt:dosage>
            <trmt:drugName>heart_med</trmt:drugName>
        </trmt:drugTreatment>
      </pat:treatment>
    </pat:treatments>
  </clin:Patient>
 <clin:Provider>
    <prov:provider-id>001</prov:provider-id>
    <prov:providerName>XYZ</prov:providerName>
    <prov:specialization>Cardiology</prov:specialization>
 </clin:Provider>
</clin:Clinic>
```

And following is my simple xquery, and as described aboved it is basically supposed to return dosage, drug and diagnosis. However, when I run the query I get the whole meta-data for the results

**Query**

```
    for $t in $clinData//clin:Patient
    where some $x in $t/pat:patient-id
    satisfies $t/pat:patient-id  = $patient-id
    return <Treatment>
    <Drug>
    {$t//treatment:drugName}
    </Drug>
    <Dosage>
     {$t//treatment:dosage}
    </Dosage>
    <Dignosis>
    {$t//treatment:diagnosis}
    </Dignosis>
    </Treatment>
```

**Result**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Treatment><Drug>heart_med</Drug><Dosage><trmt:dosage 
    xmlns:cids="http://www.example.org/schema/hosptial/clinicIds" 
    xmlns:clin="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/clinic" 
    xmlns:pat="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/patient" 
    xmlns:prov="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/provider" 
    xmlns:trmt="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/treatment" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
    instance">12.5mg</trmt:dosage></Dosage><Dignosis><trmt:diagnosis 
    xmlns:cids="http://www.example.org/schema/hosptial/clinicIds" 
    xmlns:clin="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/clinic" 
    xmlns:pat="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/patient" 
    xmlns:prov="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/provider" 
    xmlns:trmt="http://www.example.org/schema/hospital/treatment" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
    instance">Heart</trmt:diagnosis></Dignosis></Treatment>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an immediate code smell because the "satisfies" clause here:

```
where some $x in $t/pat:patient-id
    satisfies $t/pat:patient-id  = $patient-id
```

makes no reference to $x (which means that either all items in the sequence will satisfy the condition, or none will).

So (without looking at your actual logic) I guess that you probably want:

```
where some $x in $t/pat:patient-id
    satisfies $x = $patient-id
```

I don't know what $patient-id is, but I assume it's an external variable holding one or more patient IDs. If that's the case then you can get rid of the whole "where" clause and just write

```
for $t in $clinData//clin:Patient[pat:patient-id=$patient-id]...
```